# Passport context.req.user undefined after successive logins (express/graphql)

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, graphql

I'm trying to add passport.js to a graphql endpoint demo

Relevant Code:
https://gist.github.com/Falieson/855abee65621191d78575b7f28b26191#file-passport-ts-L28

loginUser mutations works, but I would expect on the second login for

> context.req.user to be passport info, not undefined

I think everything is properly set in server/server.ts

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  passport.use(Passport.Collection.createStrategy())
  passport.serializeUser(Passport.Collection.serializeUser())
  passport.deserializeUser(Passport.Collection.deserializeUser())
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyboard cat',
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true,
      store: new mongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    })
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  const rootValue = {
    me: function (args: any, req: any) {
      return req.user;
    }
  }
  app.use(
    GRAPHQL_REST,
    bodyParser.json(),
    graphqlExpress((req, res) => {
      // console.log('user: ', req.user);  
      return {
        schema,
        rootValue,
        context: {req}
      }
    })
  )
```

I guess let me know if you want a repo to reproduce with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out nothing to do with Passport or Express or my code, but an issue with graphql-playground https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-playground/issues/576